# How can I construct or return the underlying deque from a stack?

Tags: c++

I want to be able to convert a std::stack<> to a std::deque<>. Is there a straightforward conversion?

Comment: I think you'll just need to copy the data from one to another.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to do it manually:

```
while (!stk.empty())
{
    deq.push_back(stk.top());
    stk.pop();
}
```

Comment: Ah, ok - thanks. Was just wondering if I could do it without having to make a copy of the stack, and popping it into a deque.

Comment: @Stephen: Except `deque` has no such function. :)

Comment: @GMan: Holy crap, you're right.  Makes sense, given that you wouldn't know which way to grow it. I guess you could create the deque with `std::deque deq(stk.size());`, but then you can't use `push_back`.

Answer (score 19):

It is possible to access the underlying container without copying the data, but it requires a certain amount of evil. The container is exposed as a protected member, called `c`, which allows shenanigans such as this:

```
template <typename T>
class Shenanigans : private stack<T>
{
public:
    explicit Shenanigans(stack<T>& victim) : victim(victim)
    {
        swap(victim);
    }

    ~Shenanigans()
    {
        swap(victim);
    }

    using stack<T>::c;

private:
    stack<T>& victim;
};

int main()
{
    stack<int> s;
    s.push(42);

    {
        Shenanigans<int> sh(s);
        // The deque is accessible as sh.c, but the stack is temporarily empty.
        cout << "Size: " << s.size() << " Data: " << sh.c.front() << "\n";
    }

    // The stack is restored.
    cout << "Size: " << s.size() << " Data: " << s.top() << "\n";
}
```

Of course a far, far better solution is to choose a container that meets your needs.

Comment: +1:  I didn't know that it was required that the container be stored as a protected member named `c`.

Comment: This is pure **evil**. I'm both awed and terrorized.

Comment: Can you provide the implementation of swap() used above?

Comment: @user3882729 swap() is `this->swap()`, i.e. the `swap` method inherited from its parent. The Shenanigans class keeps track of the original member `victim`, but swaps the contents into itself (also a "stack") and back.

Answer (score 3):

You need to pop all the elements off of the stack and into a different container.

If you need to do this, perhaps `std::stack` is the wrong data structure for your use case.

Comment: Well - its so that I can compare stacks. The `equal` function in the standard lib, needs a container with `begin()` and `end()` functions. And I need to easily see the reverse of my stacks as well, so I thought about converting them to deques.

Comment: @BeeBand:  Why not just use a `std::deque` instead of a `std::stack` then?  It can be used for the same purpose, just instead of `top()`, `push()`, and `pop()`, you need to use `back()`, `push_back()`, and `pop_back()`.

Comment: @James - because the pop, push interface is very useful. I need `stack` functionality (i.e. `push`, `pop`, and `top` ) and don't want to call `push_back()` or `pop_back()`.

Comment: @BeeBand: But you're *not* just using `stack` functionality. If you need to see elements in reverse, it's not a stack. Just use a `deque`.

Comment: @BeeBand:  The naming of member functions is an odd reason to choose one data structure over another.  Given your use case, `std::stack` is the wrong data structure.  The right answer is to use a `std::deque`.  If the names _really_ bother you that much, then write non-member wrapper functions that do what you want; you can call those whatever you'd like.

Comment: @James... re. non member wrapper, how might I do that for a `deque`- do I not need to write an entire adaptor around a `deque`? I didn't realise you could just wrap up functions in the STL independently.. sorry - probably a whole other question in itself.

Comment: @BeeBand:  Just write a function template `top()` that takes a deque as a parameter and returns the result of calling `pop_back()` on the deque.

Comment: @BeeBand: I think he means for example `template <typename T, typename U> void push(T &con, const U &val) { con.push_back(val); }` etc. But by all means you could take the source for `stack` in your implementation, and use it as the basis to write your own complete container adaptor, with `push`, `pop`, `top`, `begin` and `end`.

Comment: "its so that I can compare stacks" - if you're just comparing stacks (of the same type), then they have an `operator==` overload. Comparing a stack to some other container is the tricky part, or seeing it in reverse.

Comment: @Steve, hmm. I didn't realise `stack` had an `operator==` overload. Well yes, actually I am going to have to iterate over the stacks also, a container adaptor might be a good idea in that case.

Answer (score 2):

I think if you need this, you would be better off using deque in the first place, instead of a stack. There is no way of getting at the underlying storage used by the stack adaptor, if that is what you are asking.

Comment: @Neil, that's exactly what I was asking yes. I see. well. The stack interface fits my needs - its just that I need to be able to compare the items in the stacks.

Comment: @BeeBand Really, a deque pretty much works like  a stack anyway - you just say pop_front and push_back instead of pop and push.

Comment: @Neil - this is true. I just like the small function names, and the idea of `back` and `front` make things confusing for what I'm doing.

Comment: @Neil - actually yes you are right. I should be using a `deque` instead.

Comment: "The stack interface fits my needs - its just that..." this is another way of saying, "The stack interface does not fit my needs" ;-)

Comment: @Steve. :) yes ok this is true, hehe.

Answer (score 0):

As all other answers have pointed out, this should never be part of the final program flow, and if your program needs the features of a deque, you should not use a stack. That being said, I can see the rare convenience for debugging and unit testing with special types to e.g. print the contents inside the stack / queue without having to alter the original container or create a copy.

An alternative evil to swapping the data back and forth is to  reinterpret the `std::stack` as an equivalent type which exposes the underlying container. This allows to e.g. provide a simple `const std::deque<T>& asDeque(const std::stack<T>&)`

```
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>

// Expose underlying container
template <typename T>
class StackHacker : std::stack<T> {
    public:
        using std::stack<T>::c;
};

// Hide the "StackHacker" wrapper
template <typename T>
const std::deque<T>& asDeque(const std::stack<T>& s) {
    return reinterpret_cast<const StackHacker<T>*>(&s)->c;
}

// Example usage to print the content of the stack
template <typename T>
void printStackContent(const std::stack<T>& s) {
    for (const T& elem : asDeque(s)) {
        std::cout << elem << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::stack<int> s;
    s.push(40);
    s.push(41);
    s.push(42);

    // The stack contains some data.
    std::cout << "Size: " << s.size() << " Data: " << s.top() << std::endl;

    // Inspect the content via the underlying deque
    std::cout << "Content of stack: " << std::endl;
    printStackContent(s);

    return 0;
}
```