# STL Priority Queue - deleting an item

Tags: c++, stl, timer, priority-queue

I want to implement a timer queuing system using the C++ STL [priority_queue](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) container adapter.

My problem is that I want to occasionally cancel a timer, however there are no interfaces that enable me to easily delete an item in the priority_queue that is not the top item.

Any suggestions?.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the exact same scenario once and did the following:

- the structure I kept in `std::priority_queue` contained only the time to sort by and an index to a `std::vector<Handler>` (in my case `Handler` was `boost::function`, but could as well be pointer to interface or function)
- when adding a timer, I'd find a free index in the vector of handlers<sup>1</sup> and store the handler at that index. Store the index and the time in the priority_queue. Return the index to the client as token to cancel
- to cancel a timer, pass the index received when adding it. Clear the handler at that index (for `boost::function` call `clear()`, if using pointers, set it to zero)
- when it's time to callback a timer, get its handler index from the priority queue and check the handlers vector - if the handler at that position is empty()/NULL, the timer has been canceled. Mark that handler index as free<sup>2</sup>.

<sup>1</sup> To make finding a free index fast, I used a separate `std::stack` of indices. When adding a timer and that stack is empty, add at the end of vector; otherwise pop the top index and use it.

<sup>2</sup> Here's the point when you push the index to the free indices stack

The whole thing is somewhat tricky and error-prone, especially if your timer callbacks need to add or cancel timers. [Here's a link to my canceling timer class described above, this code is public domain](http://codepad.org/h0kbp1x4)

Comment: I've done something similar to this as well. It's a useful pattern.

Comment: Intriguing. But I can't see how you handle the case when a timer is "cancelled" but it in fact already executed. Do you just leave it up to the calling code to wipe out any handles to a timer when that timer fires?

Comment: I think I'm going to have my queued structures store a `boost::shared_ptr<some_detail_type>` which functions as a handle for the timer. Then anyone can go into that handle and set a "cancelled" flag, to be picked up when the timer is due.

Answer (score 7):

I'm afraid STL `priority_queue` doesn't offer such functionality. You can write your own heap class (which is not that hard). You could even use the `std::xxx_heap` functions by dirty tricks like this:

```
delete_heap(iterator to_delete, iterator heap_begin, iterator heap_end)
{
  to_delete->key = something that would compare less to everything; // make sure it gets to the top in the next step
  std::push_heap(heap_begin, to_delete+1);
  std::pop_heap(heap_begin, heap_end);
}
```

which will get you `O(log n)` delete.

Comment: Intriguing. How much data would be copied by the function?

Answer (score 4):

Despite what some other answers say, it is possible to access the underlying container of any standard container adapter, including `priority_queue`, since the container is exposed as a protected member called `c`. You can either inherit from `priority_queue` and extend the interface, or use dirty tricks such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033483/how-can-i-construct-or-return-the-underlying-deque-from-a-stack/3034221#3034221) to temporarily gain access to a normal `priority_queue`.

Comment: Interesting to know that the Container member "c" is actually standardized.

Answer (score 3):

> My problem is that I want to occasionally cancel a timer, however there are no interfaces that enable me to easily delete an item in the priority_queue that is not the top item.

If canceling a timer happens often, then you need to use some different structure. std::map isn't that bad too, though cost of delete_min would go up.

If canceling a timer happens rarely, then marking the element as deleted (and ignoring it during ::pop) might do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

The STL priority_queue container is specifically designed so that only the top item is accessible, so if you need to be able to remove non-top items, you're going to have to find a different class to use.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same requirement. If you have the freedom to change the container, the one that can solve this problem is [std::set](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/) (no duplicates allowed) or [std::multiset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/multiset/).

Both are ordered and can erase an element logarithmic in container size (see the documentation for details).
For help in deleting in multi set you might want to see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9167745/in-stdmultiset-is-there-a-function-or-algorithm-to-erase-just-one-sample-unic).

See the difference [std::set vs std::priority_queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10141841/difference-between-stdset-and-stdpriority-queue) before deciding.