# In std::multiset is there a function or algorithm to erase just one sample (unicate or duplicate) if an element is found

Tags: c++, stl, multiset

Perhaps this is a duplicate but I did not find anything searching:
When `erase(value)` is called on `std::multiset` all elements with the value found are deleted. The only solution I could think of is:

```
std::multiset<int>::iterator hit(mySet.find(5));
if (hit!= mySet.end()) mySet.erase(hit);
```

This is ok but I thought there might be better. Any Ideas ?

Comment: This is a perfectly reasonable approach.

Comment: Does this approach ensures that the given key ("5") is duplicate?

Comment: @ArunSaha: No. But if its not a duplicate, I want to delete it anyhow. From the answers I got, I get the feeling that there is no better solution. Maybe the question was stupid in the first place :-P

Comment: @Martin: If you want to delete it anyhow, then what is wrong with just `erase( 5 )` which erases all copies of "5"?

Comment: @ArunSaha: Just clarified the title to make the purpose obvious

Comment: For `multimap`: is there any guarantee on which elements `find` returns? (Order of insertion? Even after such erasure? Implementation dependent?)

Comment: Honestly it's such an unobvious pitfall while using multiset which is not among the most frequently used classes.

Comment: 7 years later still wondering where `std::multiset<T>::erase_one_of` is!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since C++17 (see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset/extract)):

```
mySet.extract(val);
```

Answer (score 52):

```
auto itr = my_multiset.find(value);
if(itr!=my_multiset.end()){
    my_multiset.erase(itr);
}
```

I would imagine there is a cleaner way of accomplishing the same. But this gets the job done.

Comment: This is no different to what is in the question.

Comment: I agree! Doesn't make any sense. 12 other people saw something useful in the answer so I know i am not going crazy.

Comment: Never overlook the possibility that you're going crazy along with everyone else :)

Answer (score 48):

Try this one:

```
multiset<int> s;
s.erase(s.lower_bound(value));
```

As long as you can ensure that the `value` exists in the set. That works.

Comment: It is nice that this snippet is cleaner, however it feels less intention revealing.

Comment: @EarthenSky You can do s.erase(s.find(value))

Answer (score 4):

```
 if(my_multiset.find(key)!=my_multiset.end())
   my_multiset.erase(my_multiset.equal_range(key).first);
```

This is the best way i can think of to remove a single instance in a multiset in c++

Comment: Compared to the solution i proposed in the question your code does two searches (find + equal_range) instead of one which is inefficient

Comment: as this is same complexity, I very like this answer. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```cpp
multi_set.erase(multi_set.find(val));
```

if val exists in the multi-set.

Comment: If `val` does not exist in `multi_set`, `multi_set.find(val)` will return `multi_set.end()`. Passing and end iterator to `erase()` is undefined behavior. I wouldn't do this, even though it may work fine for some implementations.

Answer (score 2):

I would try the following.

First call `equal_range()` to find the range of elements that equal to the key.

If the returned range is non-empty, then `erase()` a range of elements (i.e. the `erase()` which takes two iterators) where:

- the first argument is the iterator to the 2nd element in the returned
  range (i.e. one past `.first` returned) and
- the second argument as the returned range pair iterator's `.second` one.

---

Edit after reading [templatetypedef](https://stackoverflow.com/users/501557/templatetypedef)'s (Thanks!) comment:

If one (as opposed to all) duplicate is supposed to be removed: If the pair returned by `equal_range()` has at least two elements, then `erase()` the first element by passing the the .first of the returned pair to single iterator version of the `erase()`:

Pseudo-code:

```
pair<iterator, iterator> pit = mymultiset.equal_range( key );

if( distance( pit.first, pit.second ) >= 2 ) {
    mymultiset.erase( pit.first );
}
```

Comment: I think the question is asking about eliminating just one duplicate, not all duplicates.

Comment: Do have an idea whether this is faster than my solution and if yes why ?

Answer (score 0):

We can do something like this:

```
multiset<int>::iterator it, it1;
it = myset.find(value);
it1 = it;
it1++;
myset.erase (it, it1);
```

Comment: Overkill. "Iterator pointing to a single element to be removed from the unordered_multiset."

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more elegant solution using "if statement with initializer" introduced in C++17:

```
if(auto it = mySet.find(value); it != mySet.end())
    mySet.erase(value);
```

The advantage of this syntax is that the scope of the iterator `it` is reduced to this `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use the [`extract`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset/extract) method from cpp17.

> If the container has an element with key equivalent to k, **unlinks the node that contains the first such element from the container** and returns a node handle that owns it. Otherwise, returns an empty node handle.

Comment: Other than actually *quoting* part of the **same cppreference page**, how is this any different from [the answer poster over 9 months ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75511604/10871073)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mSet[key].erase(mSet[key].begin());
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 auto itr=ms.find(value);  
  while(*itr==value){
  ms.erase(value);
  itr=ms.find(value);  
  }
```

Try this one It will remove all the duplicates available in the multiset.

Answer (score -2):

In fact, the correct answer is:

```
my_multiset.erase(my_multiset.find(value));
```

Comment: If _value_ doesn't exist in the multiset, it causes _undefined behaviour_.