# Insertion and Deletion of Multiset Elements while Traversing through for loop using iterators

Tags: c++, iterator, std, multiset

Here, I am performing `erase` operations and an `insert` operation on the `multiset` while traversing through the `multiset`. The Code that I have written is:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    multiset<int> ms;
    ms.insert(6);
    ms.insert(7);
    ms.insert(8);
    ms.insert(9);
    ms.insert(10);
    for(auto it = ms.begin();it != ms.end();it++){
        cout << *it << endl;
        ms.erase(it);
        if(*it == 6){
            ms.insert(4);
        }
    }
}
```

Output of the Above Code is :
6
7
4
8
9
10

I am unable to understand the output and how 4 is printing as a part of output!!

Does anyone know the explanation to the output???

I have tried different insertion and deletion operations on set while traversing through the for loop using iterators. Always getting stuck at some point and unable to understand the output!!

Comment: The intended usage of `erase(iterator)` is more akin to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9167745). I'm mostly guessing though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the [`multiset::erase` documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset/erase):

> References and iterators to the erased elements are invalidated

Therefore after this line:

```
ms.erase(it);
```

Any attempt to derefrence `it` (like you do in the next line with `*it`) is **UB** ([**Undefined Behavior**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)).
This means anything can happen.

**Some side notes:**

1. [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)
2. [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: OK, then instead of dereferencing the iterator it again in if statement,  if storing the value of *it in int x and then using this x shouldn't give us the problem right. But the Output remains same even in that Case.

Comment: You can store the value of `*it` in `int x` before calling `erase`.

Comment: In that Case, the output is again 6 7 4 8 9 10, can u please explain me how are we iterating over the set and why are we getting 4 in the output? according to my guess answer should be 6 7 8 9 10.

Comment: You cannot do it like that. Even using `it++` in the loop is actually dereferencing the `it`. One way to remove elements is to keep another `vector` with key to erase. Then iterate though this `vector` and do the actual `erase`.

Comment: Can you explain more about what you are trying to do with this code ?

Comment: gotcha!! there is nothing particular I am trying here, I was exploring my ways with iterators and data structures and stuck at this point!! Now I understand that it gives us Undefined Behavior in this scenario!! Thanks for help man!!