# How to remove element not at top from priority_queue?

Tags: c++, stl, priority-queue, binary-heap

In my program I need to delete an element from a priority queue that is not at the top. Can that be done? If not, please suggest a way to do so except creating your own heap.

Comment: Why a have you specifically chosen a priority queue if it doesn't support the operations you want?  Why not instead choose a data structure which *does* support those operations, like a set?

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley   because i need both behaviors.

Comment: Which behaviors?  Fast access to the max (or min) element? `set` has that.  Quick removal of arbitrary elements? `set` has that too.

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley oh really!! i didn't know that....i'll check :)

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley  but sets have unique elements and i need duplicate elements

Comment: Then use a [multiset](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset).

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley if i am not wrong multisets are implemented as BST right?

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley i am not able to find out how to get the min/max in multiset.....could you please tell me?

Comment: `*mySet.begin()`, `*mySet.rbegin()`. Since a set is ordered, the first and last elements are the smallest and the largest, correspondingly.

Comment: Following SO post also having same problem you can refer it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076163/stl-priority-queue-deleting-an-item/3076722#3076722

Comment: possible duplicate of [STL Priority Queue - deleting an item](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076163/stl-priority-queue-deleting-an-item)

Comment: One could also use a set of pairs (item, i), where i as an integer increased for every item. Then the elements appear unique. One has to store the i value in the item without it affecting the comparator.

Comment: @ishan3243 This question still shows up as unanswered. Wasn't alexm's answer spot on?

Answer (score 64):

The standard `priority_queue<T>` can be customized through inheritance. It has protected members `c` and `comp` that can be referenced in a descendant class.

```
template<typename T>
class custom_priority_queue : public std::priority_queue<T, std::vector<T>>
{
  public:

      bool remove(const T& value) {
          auto it = std::find(this->c.begin(), this->c.end(), value);
       
          if (it == this->c.end()) {
              return false;
          }
          if (it == this->c.begin()) {
              // deque the top element
              this->pop();
          }    
          else {
              // remove element and re-heap
              this->c.erase(it);
              std::make_heap(this->c.begin(), this->c.end(), this->comp);
         }
         return true;
     }
};

void main()
{
   custom_priority_queue<int> queue;

   queue.push(10);
   queue.push(2);
   queue.push(4);
   queue.push(6);
   queue.push(3);

   queue.remove(6);

   while (!queue.empty())
   {
      std::cout << queue.top();
      queue.pop();

      if (!queue.empty())
      {
        std::cout << ", ";
      }
   }

 }
```

Output:

10, 4, 3, 2

Comment: The call to `make_heap` isn't necessary since the heap remains ordered.

Comment: @alexm If I want to pass a custom comparator to the object, how do I write the class declaration?

Comment: @SandeepTuniki: If you want to pass a custom comparator, the class declaration could look like this: `template<typename T, class Container=std::vector<T>, class Compare=std::less<typename Container::value_type>>
class custom_priority_queue : public std::priority_queue<T, Container, Compare>`

Comment: @klaustriendl, could you explain why `make_heap` is unnecessary, especially if the removed item happen to be at the top / multiple items were removed? My guess is that `make_heap` is unnecessary only if heap is fully sorted which is not the case.

Comment: @Aelian You are absolutely right, and thank you for detecting my mistake. It seems I misunderstood the properties of a heap, so I mistakened "sorted" for "structured". So if you remove an element you need to restructure the heap.

Comment: you could check if "it" equals this->c.begin(), if not, no need to call make_heap after erase()

Comment: @foddex : added special case when the found item is on the top of the queue.

Answer (score 50):

The best solution is to use std::set. Sets provide methods which allow it to be used both as a min/max heap (or a priority queue).

```
std::set<int> pq;

//accessing the smallest element(use as min heap)
*pq.begin();

//accessing the largest element (use as max heap)
*pq.rbegin();
```

Furthermore sets also allow random deletion.

```
//to delete the integer '6'
auto it = pq.find(6);
pq.erase(it);
```

Comment: This solution won't work if the elements can repeat.

Comment: I think the idea is cool, you can use multiset for repeating elements. But remember to pay attention when you are erasing by value instead of iterator.

Comment: For repeated elements you can simply use a map. Just keep a count of keys and when the count of a key becomes 0, remove the key. Solved this problem using the same idea https://www.spoj.com/problems/ARRAYSUB/

Comment: @VipulJain You could always use a multi-set.

Answer (score 14):

A neat little trick to handle deletes for a priority_queue STL - use another priority_queue, say, `del_pq`. Keep inserting all the delete values to this. When you are popping values from the original priority queue, check with top of `del_pq` and see if we wanted to delete it. If it matches, delete the value from the original priority_queue.

This method implements a way to lazily delete the values in our original priority queue. Can take up twice the memory, but average delete and inserts remain `O(logN)`.

Comment: I am not sure if the element at the top is always the answer, but using unordered_set (or similar) for the deletion should also work in sublinear time.

Answer (score 5):

Pradip and MASh sacrifice the time to realize the remove operation.
But if time complexity is important to you, I suggest you to use hash min_heap.
A Hash table stores the value-pointer and the pointers point to a min_heap.
Which means you can spend O(1) time to find the value in min_heap and O(log(n)) to remove(sift-up or sift down) the element.

Comment: Never sacrifice the time.

Answer (score 0):

My C++ is quite rusty - here I provide a C# solution that I hope can be easily translated to C++.

The idea is to subclass the standard C# class [**PriorityQueue**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.priorityqueue-2?view=net-8.0) and add a ***Remove*** method. Here is  the code - for readability I am using an instance of ***PriorityQueue<int, int>*** - this could be easily generalized to ***PriorityQueue<TElement, TPriority>***

```cs
    public class MyHeap 
    {
        private PriorityQueue<int, int> _theQueue = new PriorityQueue<int, int>();
        private HashSet<int> _deleted = new HashSet<int>();

        public void Add(int v)
        {
            _deleted.Remove(v);
            _theQueue.Enqueue(v, v);
        }

        public void Remove(int v)
        {
            _deleted.Add(v);
        }

        public int GetMinimum()
        {
            var qMin = _theQueue.Peek();
            while(_deleted.Contains(qMin))
            {
                _theQueue.Dequeue();
                _deleted.Remove(qMin);
                qMin = _theQueue.Peek();
            }
            return qMin;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -4):

> **Please note** *the following approach does the things but not the optimized way to solution. For optimized approach, check other
> answers.*

Let you want to delete the 5th element in the `priority_queue<type> Q` .
Then you can do this like:

```
vector<type> tempQ;
int i = 0;
int n = 5;
type t;

// backup n-1 items
while(i < n-1)
{
    tempQ.push_back(Q.top());
    Q.pop();        
    i++;
}

// remove the nth item
Q.pop();

// restore the backed up items
i = 0;
while(i < n-1)
{
    t = tempQ[i++];
    Q.push(t);
}
```

Comment: So what is the complexity of this method ? I do not see the need of using a temporary PQ. why not use a vector `vector<type> tempQ`

Comment: Good point, here we just need a container. I using a vector instead will improve time complexity. I updated the answer. +1 for your point @kevin