# Deleting element in priority queue other than top element in C++

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl, heap, priority-queue

Is there any inbuilt function for deleting a given element (other than top element) in priority queue class of C++ STL? If not how to delete it in O(log n)?Should i implement the heap data structure from scratch for this 'delete' functionality?

Comment: If you need to remove arbitrary elements from a container, then perhaps a queue is not the right choice? How about a `std::deque` that you do sorted insertions on? You could easily wrap it up in a container-adapter with a similar interface to `std::priority_queue`.

Comment: btw `std::vector` is a much better default than "implement from scratch". It doesn't have O(log n) erase, but it has O(0) complexity for getting the implementation right ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any inbuilt function for deleting a given element (other than top element) in priority queue class of C++ STL?

No.

> If not how to delete it in O(log n)?

By using another container. `std::set` is the simplest compromise. A custom heap implementation may be more optimal.

Answer (score 0):

There is no inbuilt function for deleting a given element(other than top element) in priority queue.

I would recommend you to use ***std::set*** which performs the operations in ***O(logN)*** by implementing binary tree. But in case you need more better time complexity use ***std::unordered_set*** which performs operations in ***O(1)*** time and uses hashing.

So my advice will be that use ***std::set*** or ***std::unordered_set*** & don't restrict yourself to priority queue only.

Answer (score 0):

As [suggested by this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36711682/170521), you can do something like this:

```
template<typename T>
class custom_priority_queue : public std::priority_queue<T, std::vector<T>>
{
  public:

    template< typename UnaryPredicate >
    T pop_match_or_top(UnaryPredicate p) {
        auto it = std::find_if(this->c.begin(), this->c.end(), p);
        if (it != this->c.end()) {
            T value = std::move(*it);
            this->c.erase(it);
            std::make_heap(this->c.begin(), this->c.end(), this->comp);
            return value;
       }
       else {
            T value = this->top();
            this->pop();
            return value;
       }
   }
};
```

This is specially useful when you need to take elements that are close to the top but are not exactly the top.