# C++ priority_queue: modify STL template to search & delete element of pair not at top w/ criteria on 1st element in pair

Tags: c++, stl, priority-queue, std-pair

I want to modify the `<queue>` STL so that it can find any element from the `priority_queue`, then delete it from the `pq`. The code is based on the answer by alexm from [How to remove element not at top from priority_queue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19467485/how-to-remove-element-not-at-top-from-priority-queue)

However, what I want to achieve is more complicated: the element in the `priority_queue` is `pair<char, double>`, and I want to achieve a min-heap. Thus, I modified the code as below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;
using item_type = pair<char, double>;

template<typename T>
class custom_priority_queue : public priority_queue<T, vector<T>, greater<>> {
public:
    bool eleExist(const T& value) {
        auto it = lower_bound(this->c.begin(), this->c.end(), value);
        if (it != this->c.end())
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    
    bool remove(const T& value) {
        auto it = lower_bound(this->c.begin(), this->c.end(), value);
        if (it != this->c.end()) {
            this->c.erase(it);
            make_heap(this->c.begin(), this->c.end(), this->comp);
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    custom_priority_queue<item_type> pq;

    // use list to fill priority_queue later
    // larger number means higher priority
    initializer_list<item_type> il {
        {'A', 10},
        {'B', 12},
        {'H', 12}
    };
    // iterator through list to fill into priority_queue
    for (const auto& item : il) {
        pq.emplace(item);
    }
    
    if (pq.eleExist({'A', 10})) {
        cout << "A exists. Thus remove it" << endl;
        pq.remove({'A', 10});
    }
    else
        cout << "A doens't exist" << endl;

    // print priority_queue
    cout << "Currently in priority queue:" << endl;
    while (!pq.empty()) {
        cout << pq.top().first << ": " << pq.top().second << endl;
        pq.pop();
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, I can only use `eleExist` and `remove` functions with the full pair in my `main` function. What I really want to achieve is, to find element in `priority_queue` based on the 1st element in `pair`, and is able to delete the `pair` element based on the `eleExist` function. How do I modify my derived class `custom_priority_queue` to achieve that?

Thanks.

Comment: Consider using "lower_bound()" (O(log(n)) instead of "find()" (O(n)). Priority queues are sorted, and this in turn allows for a fast search (O(log(n))). The use of "find" degrades performance here.

Comment: Attempting to subclass `priority_queue` is completely the wrong way to go about it. The correct way to use the `priority_queue` is to implement a custom comparator. This is standard `priority_queue` functionality, see your C++ textbook for more information.

Comment: Hi @Sam Varshavchik, how can a comparator achieve the goal of finding and deleting ANY element from the `priority_queue`? By ANY, I mean the element might not be at the top of the `priority_queue`. Can you be specific? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @RonaldSouza. I modified codes in my question based on your suggestion.

Comment: @RonaldSouza Priority queue is not fully sorted, as it's a heap structure. lower_bound on a heap won't work correctly.

Comment: It looks like you could use a sorted `vector` instead of a `priority_queue`. Then you can search in it quickly using `lower_bound`. But! Removing one element in the middle of a `vector` is an O(N) operation as all remaining elements have to be moved. If you remove frequently, then a binary tree (`std::map`) might be more efficient. Benchmark to be sure.

Comment: @rustyx True. Thank you. But still, to use "find" in a heap structure does not seem to be the way to go.

Comment: @rustyx +1 for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looking for exact value with `std::find`, you might use the version with predicate (`std::find_if`):

```
template<typename T>
class custom_priority_queue : public std::priority_queue<T, std::vector<T>, std::greater<>> {
public:
    template <typename Pred>
    bool contains_if(Pred pred) const {
        auto it = std::find_if(this->c.begin(), this->c.end(), pred);
        return it != this->c.end();
    }
    
    template <typename Pred>
    bool remove_if(Pred pred) {
        const auto old_size = this->size();
        this->c.erase(std::remove_if(this->c.begin(), this->c.end(), pred), this->c.end());
        if (old_size == this->size()) return false;
        std::make_heap(this->c.begin(), this->c.end(), this->comp);
        return true;
    }
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5058bbbe041089a0)

Comment: Thanks @Jarod42. What's the time complexity of using `find_if` and `remove_if`combined w/ `erase` then? Based on https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find, all 3 function should be `O(n)`?

Comment: Yes. all are `O(n)`.

Comment: Thanks again @Jarod42. Is there a way of realizing what I want in `O(logN)`: 1) I don't need a fully-sorted data structure for every step. Instead, I only care the smallest element (each element is a `pair`, comparison is based on `pair.second`); 2) However, I frequently search elements in the data structure based on `pair.first`, and need to delete that element based on my search.