# priority_queue - delete not a top elements

Tags: c++, stl, queue, std

I have priority_queue. My function delete not very rational in terms of memory consumption and time.
I've seen similar themes, but they did not help me.

[How to remove element not at top from priority_queue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19467485/c-priority-queue-removing-element-not-at-top)

[STL Priority Queue - deleting an item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076163/stl-priority-queue-deleting-an-item)

How i can delete elements on log( n ).

My function:

## 1

```
void deleteFromTimeQueue(const K& key)
            {
                std::priority_queue<Record<K>, std::vector<Record<K>>, Comparator<K>> tmpTimeQueue_;

                while (timeQueue_.size() > 0)
                {
                    Record<K> it = timeQueue_.top();

                    if (it.getKey() == key)
                    {
                        timeQueue_.pop();
                        break;
                    }
                    tmpTimeQueue_.push(it);
                    timeQueue_.pop();
                }

                while (tmpTimeQueue_.size() > 0)
                {
                    Record<K> it = tmpTimeQueue_.top();
                    timeQueue_.push(it);
                    tmpTimeQueue_.pop();
                }
            }
```

How i can delete elements whitout **tmpTimeQueue_**?

## 2

```
void deleteFromTimeQueue(const K& key)
        {
            std::priority_queue<Record<K>, std::vector<Record<K>>, Comparator<K>> tmpTimeQueue_;

            while (timeQueue_.size() > 0)
            {
                Record<K> it = timeQueue_.top();

                if (it.getKey() == key)
                {
                    timeQueue_.pop();
                    continue;
                }
                tmpTimeQueue_.push(it);
                timeQueue_.pop();
            }
            timeQueue_.swap(tmpTimeQueue_);
        }
```

**What number better 1 or 2?**

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3076273/1741297) has nailed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe implementing Priority-queue using LINK-LIST can be a good ideal. By that, you can search for the element and delete it as normal link list. Hope this can be helpful for you.

Comment: Unfortunately this also means you have O(n) complexity for every insert as well. It may be an option for the OP if the list is small enough, but as a general solution, heaps are considerably more efficient for what priority queues are *supposed* to be used for: insertions and *front*-removals. I'd rather introduce an O(NlogN) for exception cases if it meant my mainline kept O(logN).