# std::random_shuffle with a std::queue

Tags: c++, collections, queue, std, shuffle

How can I apply the `std::random_shuffle` algorithm with a `std::queue`? I tried this:

```
std::random_shuffle(myQueue.front(), myQueue.back());
```

And gives errors:

- No match for 'operator-' in '__i- __first'
- No match for 'operator!=' in '__first != __last'
- No match for 'operator+' in '__first + 1'
- No match for 'operator++' in '++ __i'

My queue is holding `Card` classes, which represent poker cards. I can understand that the error comes from the operations which `std::random_shuffle` is doing with the queue elements So, even when I don't need a `!= operator` for my `Card` class, i wrote one and that error is gone.

But what should I do with the rest of the errors? It makes no sense to write `operators +, - and ++` for a `Card` class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::queue` is not a container; it's a container adapter. It adapts a sequence container to restrict its interface to simple queue/dequeue operations. In particular, it doesn't let you (easily) iterate over the underlying container, which is what `std::random_shuffle` needs to do. If you don't want those restrictions, don't use `std::queue`; use a sequence container (such as `vector` or `deque`) directly.

There are [ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3034221/204847) to subvert its interface and meddle with the underlying container, but it would be much better to choose an appropriate container to start with.

Comment: Ok, I understand the problem, but I have one doubt here: if deque is a double-queue, why can it have iterators and a queue can't? Makes the same sense to me

Comment: @RomanRdgz: Because `queue` is an adapter, not a container. It wraps up a container (by default, a `deque`) and presents a simpler, more specific, interface.

Answer (score 3):

`std::random_shuffle` expects a pair of iterators. Furthermore, an `std::queue` is not designed to be messed around like that. It maintains the order of its elements by definition. What you can do is create an `std::deque`, shuffle that, and the construct a queue from it.

```
std::deque<int> d {5, 1, 67, 89, 32, 444}; // populate in the order you would the queue
std::random_shuffle(d.begin(), d.end());
std::queue<int> q(d);
```

Comment: Would this be neccessary? I mean, once I'm using a std::deque, wouldn't it be better to stay with it using its pop_front and push_front methods?

Comment: @RomanRdgz If you need a queue, better stick with `std::queue`. `std::deque` supports all kinds of operations that a queue shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

`std::random_shuffle` expects two iterators, but `std::queue::front()` and `std::queue::back()` return two references to elements. `std::queue` does not expose iterators, you it only offers an interface to push back and pop front elements. If you need to iterate over a collection use `std::deque` (or any of the standard containers).