# How to preallocate(reserve) a priority_queue<vector>?

Tags: c++, vector, std, priority-queue, allocation

How can I preallocate a `std::priority_queue` with a container of type `std::vector`?

```
std::priority_queue<unsigned char, std::vector<unsigned char>> pq;
pq.c.reserve(1024);
```

Does not compile because the underlying vector is a protected member.
Is it possible to use the constructor of the `priority_queue` to wrap it around a pre-reserved vector?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, there's a [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/priority_queue) for that. It's slightly tedious that you also have to specify a comparator:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> container;
container.reserve(1024);
std::priority_queue<unsigned char, std::vector<unsigned char>> pq (
    std::less<unsigned char>(), std::move(container));
```

You can also use [evil shenanigans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033483/how-can-i-construct-or-return-the-underlying-deque-from-a-stack/3034221#3034221) to access the protected member, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Doesn't work for `vector<pair<int, int>> container2; container2.reserve(1024); priority_queue<pair<int, int>, vector<pair<int, int>>> minheap (greater<pair<int, int>>(), move(container2));`?

Comment: @HuXixi you have to specify the comparator type in the template arguments: `vector<pair<int, int>> container2; container2.reserve(1024); priority_queue<pair<int, int>, vector<pair<int, int>>, greater<pair<int,int>>> minheap (greater<pair<int, int>>(), move(container2));`

Answer (score 6):

Another solution might be to make your own class derived from std::priority_queue, such as:

```
class MyPQueue : public std::priority_queue<unsigned char, std::vector<unsigned char>>
{
public:
    MyPQueue(size_t reserve_size)
    {
        this->c.reserve(reserve_size);
    }
};
```

then, in the code, create a MyPQueue object in this way:

```
MyPQueue mpq(1024);
```

which object can be upcasted back to the base class whenether needed.

```
std::priority_queue<unsigned char, std::vector<unsigned char>>& pq = mpq;
```

Answer (score 3):

With `C++14`, we can write

```
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <functional>

template <class T>
auto make_reserved(const std::size_t n)
{
  std::vector<T> v;
  v.reserve(n);
  return v;
}

template <class T>
auto make_queue(const std::size_t n)
{
    return std::priority_queue<T>(std::less<T>(), make_reserved<T>(n));
}

int main()
{
  auto q = make_queue<int>(100);
  q.push(1);
  q.push(2);
  std::cout << q.size() << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to comment on Mike Seymour's post, but he ommited the third template argument of `std::priority_queue` :

```
std::vector<unsigned char> container;
container.reserve(1024);
std::priority_queue<unsigned char, std::vector<unsigned char>, std::less<unsigned char>> pq(std::less<unsigned char>(), std::move(container));
```

It is quite verbose for sure, but it does the work.