# How to preallocate memory for priority queue?

Tags: c++, constructor, stl, comparator, priority-queue

Presently i'm trying to implement this solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29236236/8882282
And I have no problems when i'm using less<>(), but have a lot of them in any other cases(greater, my own comparator). 
For example:

```
std::vector<long long int> container;
container.reserve(dimension);
std::priority_queue<long long int, std::vector<long long int>> queue(std::greater<long long int>(), std::move(container));
```

"No matching constructor"

Have you any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default comparator for a `std::priority_queue` is `std::less`. You're passing in a `std::greater` comparator to the constructor.

They are different, completely unrelated, classes. That's your error.

You must explicitly declare your priority queue, as such:

```
std::priority_queue<long long int,
                    std::vector<long long int>,
                    std::greater<long long int>>
          queue(std::greater<long long int>(),
                std::move(container));
```