# "error: no matching function for call to 'std::priority_queue<int>::priority_queue(int)' priority_queue<int> pqueue(4); "

Tags: c++, oop, stl, queue, priority-queue

I tried to allocate memory to the `priority_queue` using the `constructor`, but getting the below error:

> No matching constructor for initialization of 'priority_queue pq(3)'

why this is not working in `priority_queue` but working correctly in `vector`s?

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <queue> 
using namespace std; 

int main() 
{ 

priority_queue<int> pqueue(4); 
pqueue.push(3); 
pqueue.push(5); 
pqueue.push(1); 
pqueue.push(2); 

}
```

Comment: Even for `std::vector` this would not just allocate memory, but initialize it as well. Your example would yield a vector containing (0,0,0,0,3,5,1,2). Be aware of that.

Answer (score 2):

[related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29235978/9200752)

`std::priority_queue` doesn't have such [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/priority_queue), but the below code implements what you want:

```cpp
std::vector<int> temporary_container(4);

std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>> pqueue (comparator, std::move(container));
```

Also if you want not to change the size of `queue` and only reserve memory, you can do it like below:

```cpp
std::vector<int> temporary_container;
temporary_container.reserve(4);

std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>> pqueue (comparator, std::move(container));
```

Using this ways, you should define your `comparator` and pass it to the `constructor`.

Comment: You didn't mention any difference between priority_queue and vector which answer the question: "why this is not working in priority_queue but working correctly in vectors?".

Comment: @HoseynHeydari `queue` has its own concept. It's not `vector` and we won't access randomly to each element or change their value, so maybe it's not useful generally to en-queue several elements with a value of `0` (which are all equivalent), at starting. Anyway, this constructor is not implemented for `std::queue` and that is the reason we can not use it.

Answer (score 0):

A `std::priority_queue` has a restrictive interface, isn't the same thing as a `std::vector` and doesn't have that constructor.

See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/priority_queue for constructor summary.

To fix the compile error, you may just do instead:

```
priority_queue<int> pqueue{};
```

Comment: Actually, you can use constructor (3) and pass in a preinitialized `std::vector`. Doesn't help for memory allocation though, as it just copy constructs the internal container.